# Python 2: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scan'

Tags: python, import, attributeerror

I'm currently learning Python with the book "Learn python the hard way" and I'm getting an error.

I have a folder called `ex48` where a `lexicon.py` is located. In this `lexicon.py` I have 'scan' function, which gets one input, splits it and identifies the words, then returns a list.:

```
def scan(self, input):
    identifiedWords = []
    words = input.split(" ")
    for i in len(words):
        # check if it's a number first
        try:
            identifiedWords[i] = ('number', int(words[i]))
        except ValueError:
            # directions
            if words[i].lower() == 'north':
                identifiedWords[i] = ('direction', 'north')
            elif words[i].lower() == 'east':
                identifiedWords[i] = ('direction', 'east')
```

...

```
            # error
            else:
            identifiedWords[i] = ('error', words[i])

    return identifiedWords
```

Outside of my `ex48` folder I'm trying to use this function in powershell.
I'm doing:

```
>>> from ex48 import lexicon
>>> lexicon.scan("north south")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scan'
>>>
```

The function **should** return `[('direction', 'north'), ('direction', 'south')`

Am I doing something wrong with the import or is the syntax of the scan function wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To mark ex48 as a Python module, you have to create an empty file called `__init__.py`
Also, the scan method contains the argument "self", which makes it a class method. You have to initialize the class before using the method.

Edit:
I see, you have a class called `Lexicon` inside the module called `lexicon`. You have to first init your class and then call the function:

```
from ex48 import lexicon
lex = lexicon.Lexicon()
lex.scan("north south")
```

Comment: I already had an __init__.py, is that the same? Also, after removing the "self" I am still getting the error. [link to the full lexicon.py](https://hastebin.com/lunekoledu.py)

Comment: Oh i see, you had underscores. But yes, I had that file.

Comment: you can keep the "self" parameter, but you have to call it like this:
lex = lexicon.Lexicon()
lex.scan("north south")

Comment: @squeezyPig unless there's a good reason to have the `Lexicon` class, your code would be simpler if you moved the `scan` method outside of the `Lexicon` class (and removed `self`), like in [this example](https://github.com/wzpan/Learn-Python-The-Hard-Way/blob/master/Python2/ex48/skeleton/ex48/lexicon.py).

Answer (score 0):

Wrong usage of self is whats giving you the problem :
https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/

```
def scan(input):
    ....
```

should solve it. The link is to understand why.

Comment: I removed the self and I am still getting the problem. [link to the full lexicon.py](https://hastebin.com/lunekoledu.py)